# How to assign bar colors in Google bar chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

I have a chart built from two data series, each having 2 values.  How can I make the bar representing the first value in the first series have a different color than the bar representing first value in the second series.

Here's how I'm setting up the series.

```
chartData[0] = ['Type', 'Scheduled', 'Actual', {role: 'style'}]
                chartData[1] = ['Today', data['exchanges']['Planned']['Today'], data['exchanges']['Actual']['Today'], ''];
                chartData[2] = ['Overdue', data['exchanges']['Planned']['Overdue'], data['exchanges']['Actual']['Overdue'], ''];
```

Then I set the series option like this:

`series: [{color: "#001E60"}, {color: "#BDC667"}]`

This sets the same color for the first bar for both series like this:

[image]
.
What I would like to do is set the color of the Overdue bar with color #001E60 to red but can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you discovered, both the colors and series options color the series the same.

you must use the style role to color bars in the same series different colors.

the style role column must follow the series column it should be applied to.

you have included the style role in your example, but is included only for one series, and it is blank.

```
chartData[0] = ['Type', 'Scheduled', {role: 'style'}, 'Actual', {role: 'style'}]
  chartData[1] = ['Today', data['exchanges']['Planned']['Today'], 'red', data['exchanges']['Actual']['Today'], 'green'];
  chartData[2] = ['Overdue', data['exchanges']['Planned']['Overdue'], 'blue', data['exchanges']['Actual']['Overdue'], 'green'];
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great, just had to swap the 'red' and 'blue' since I wanted the red on the Overdue series.

Have one more problem to deal with.  The legend now shows blue as the Scheduled color, and red as the Actual color, and green isn't included at all.  IS there some way I can customize the legend to include all three colors, so blue as "Scheduled", green as "Actual", and red as perhaps just "Overdue"?

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if it might just be easier to make this into two separate charts, one for Today and one for Overdue, each with it's own legend.

Comment: the legend follows the colors in the colors / series options. the style role will invalidate the legend. you can use separate charts or build your own legend...

Comment: Thanks, I figured that was the reason.  I think I will split the existing chart into 2 separate ones, THanks for your help.